# How to correctly call a function from one class inside another class

Tags: python, class, kivy

I am unable to get my spaceship image to load onto the screen with this code. The window opens but there is nothing but black. If the code inside           `class moveShip(Widget)` were to be put inside `class mainApp(App)` the ship DOES appear. I would like to know how I can call the `moveShip(Widget)` class correctly so that I can see my image on the screen.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class moveShip(Widget):
    def move(self):
        # moving the ship along the y axis

        f = FloatLayout()
        s = Scatter(do_rotation=False, do_scale=False,
                  do_translation_x=False)
        ship = Image(source = 'assets/pictures/ship.jpg')

        f.add_widget(s)
        s.add_widget(ship)
        return f

class mainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sh = moveShip()
        sh.move()
        return sh

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainApp().run()
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? You're instantiating your `moveShip` class and calling its `move()` function.

Comment: the ship image does not appear when I call the funciton

Comment: What does that have to do with correctly calling a function? `move()` is being called. You must be doing something wrong *inside* `move()`.

Comment: maybe so, and if I am do not know what. If I put all the code from move() into build() instead the ship appears. But it will not like this and I'm really confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never add the widgets in your `move` method to anything, so they're naturally not displayed anywhere. You could do e.g. `self.add_widget(f)` to see them.

You also probably don't quite want this, you should add the widgets in the `__init__` method (e.g. `self.layout = FloatLayout()`) then *change* them later, rather than creating and adding new ones (e.g. `self.scatter.pos = ...` if you added a self.scatter attribute).

I also recommend using kv language where possible, and giving your widget classes names starting with an upper case letter because kv uses this to distinguish them from properties (this is also a standard python convention).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you wanted me to do but I added {self.add_widget(f)} to the bottom of my move() function and sure enough it works. Thanks alot.